# tensorflow_datasets.load() downloads but cannot extract certain datasets

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

Calling tensorflow_datasets.load('cycle_gan/apple2orange') works fine
but tensorflow_datasets.load('cycle_gan/vangogh2photo') gives me an error.

I've tried this on my desktop and laptop and both gave the same error message.
Here's the code I ran and the error message I got:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
dataset = tfds.load('cycle_gan/vangogh2photo',
                    data_dir='data', batch_size=1, download=True, in_memory=False)
```

```
InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: data\downloads\extracted\ZIP.peop.eecs.berk.edu_taes_park_Cycl_data_vanNiw0c-cL4JRL2gjUnWYOr9woVN9V1peDW4GG0decqv8.zip.incomplete_bf327518b23f41ee9a3a469cc0b541ba\vangogh2photo\testB\2014-12-10 12:08:40.jpg : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
; Unknown error
```

then it says

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

(traceback)

```
ExtractError: Error while extracting data\downloads\peop.eecs.berk.edu_taes_park_Cycl_data_vanNiw0c-cL4JRL2gjUnWYOr9woVN9V1peDW4GG0decqv8.zip to data\downloads\extracted\ZIP.peop.eecs.berk.edu_taes_park_Cycl_data_vanNiw0c-cL4JRL2gjUnWYOr9woVN9V1peDW4GG0decqv8.zip : Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: data\downloads\extracted\ZIP.peop.eecs.berk.edu_taes_park_Cycl_data_vanNiw0c-cL4JRL2gjUnWYOr9woVN9V1peDW4GG0decqv8.zip.incomplete_bf327518b23f41ee9a3a469cc0b541ba\vangogh2photo\testB\2014-12-10 12:08:40.jpg : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
; Unknown error
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using?

There is an issue with some datasets on Windows when composing the URLs to fetch the files or the URLs where to save them locally.

For the Oxford Pets III dataset, the link below provides the fix:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31171#issuecomment-529169445

Perhaps something similar may apply here?